# How might you improve upon the following method?

Tags: javascript, html, mysql

I have been asked the question of how to improve the code below. Any suggestions would be helpful! I'm thinking this is supposed to be a very simple question with very simple answers.

```
 public List getPlanets(DataSource d, String galaxy) throws SQLException
{
   Connection c;
   Statement s;
   ResultSet rs;
   Planet p;

   c = d.getConnection();
   s = c.createStatement();
   rs = s.executeQuery("select * from planets where galaxy = '" + galaxy + "'");

   List l = new ArrayList();

   while (rs.next())
   {
      p = new Planet();

      p.setName(rs.getString("name"));
      p.setDiameter(rs.getString("diameter"));
      p.setMass(rs.getString("mass"));
      l.add(p);
   }

   return l;
}
```

Comment: I think you should use a parameterized query instead of plain SQL with concatenation. This is bad programming practice not to use a parameterized query. Also instead of setting each property of planet one by one, just make another constructor and pass **rs** object to it, which can set values accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

If you know that you are only getting 3 specific items from the query - target them and don't use the wildcard ("*") in the query. Remember that this symbol means "get all results"

The wildcard may be fine if the results are small - but imagine if there are 1000 data points per row - you are getting all of them and then only using 3.

```
rs = s.executeQuery("SELECT name, diameter, mass FROM planets WHERE galaxy = '" + galaxy + "'");
```

Also - I agree with @AhmerMH regarding the parametised query.